# delete table view multiple rows from a custom button action using [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths withRowAnimation in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

i have a edit button and delete button. when edit button tap table view set editing mode on from left side of table view.i already do this. but when select row and tap to the delete button how to use this method

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths=@"indexpath"   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

i can delete data but can not use this method from delete method. i need it because after delete button tap, set editing mode gone, and table view update with animation. if i reload table view its not animated.

Comment: Saad your question is not clear.Give more details and ask what you want to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
-(void)onButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender {

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        int index = indexPath.row;
        [arrDataSource removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
```

Comment: where i get indexpath? i said delete is a custom button action.

Answer (score 0):

I created Custom Button Edit and Delete with action.Delete button deletes the row successfully.It works fine.I worked with sample one for your question.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewDeleterow;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
   NSMutableArray *arrTableData;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tableViewDeleterow;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    arrTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"iPhone",@"iPad",@"iTV",@"iWatch",nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//UITableView DataSource methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return arrTableData.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *strCell = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
   }

   //Custom Edit Button
   UIButton *btnEdit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   btnEdit.frame = CGRectMake(0,4,100, 20);
   [btnEdit setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [btnEdit setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [btnEdit addTarget:self action:@selector(actionEdit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnEdit.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnEdit];

    //Custom Delete Button
    UIButton *btnDelete = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnDelete.frame = CGRectMake(250,4,100, 20);
    [btnDelete setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnDelete setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(actionDelete:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnDelete.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnDelete];

    return cell;
}

-(void)actionEdit:(UIButton *)sender
{
   //do stuff here for edit action
}

-(void)actionDelete:(UIButton *)sender
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) sender.superview.superview;
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableViewDeleterow indexPathForCell:cell];
   NSLog(@"The selected indexPath.row is - %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
   [arrTableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [tableViewDeleterow deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }

@end
```

When I delete the 2nd index path delete row,the printed result is

```
The selected indexPath.row is - 2
```

**At intial**

[image]

After deleting the second index path row delete button

[image]